# jquery "scroll" problem

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to modify this script;

```
<script>
function doIt2() {
  $("div.formbut").hide("slow");  
  $("div.inqform").show("slow");  
  }
$("submit2").click(doIt2);
$("form").submit(function () {
  if ($("input").val() == "yes") {
    $("p").show(4000, function () {
      $(this).text("Ok, loaded! (now showing)");
   });
  }
  $("div.rates").hide("slow");
  $("div.ratesbut").hide("slow");  
  $("div.inqform").hide("slow");
  $("div.done").show("slow");
  return false; 
});
</script>
```

What I wanted to do is, scroll to the top of the "inqform" div. could not..
Then tried to scroll to bottom of the page.. I could not do that either..
I wanted it to happen after "  $("div.inqform").show("slow");  " 
I do not understand much of js..

Can anybody help ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: To prevent jQuery from searching the whole DOM-tree every time you want to access an element, you should cache the jQuery objects in variables; `var $formbut = $("div.formbut");`.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert below code after `$("div.inqform").show("slow");` to scroll to top of it -

```
var targetOffset = $('div.inqform').offset().top;
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 500);
```

Comment: @Has: consider accepting the answer instead of leaving a *thank you* comment!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to put this script live.. but noticed that the form is not being posted.
there is a inquiry form in the `div.inqform`

```
$("div.inqform").hide("slow");
```

The `done` action is done.. but the form is not posted.

wondering.. now.. do we need to wait `document.ready` until form is submitted to show div.done ?